# sendmail.php not re-directing

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I had/have the code below for users to send messages/emails from my website to my sites email address.

It was working fine, for weeks: Validating the field contents (if there was a blank 'required field', it asked for a "valid" field content i.e. email address), as long as there were no blank fields it was sending the email and was re-directing to the thank-you page - which acknowledges that the email has been sent.

Now, it has stopped working properly.

It doesn't seem to be validating (as it did originally) any more - as there are no warnings/errors for blank fields (if there is a blank field it simply doesn't send), it still sends the email to the address correctly (if there are no blank required fields), but it doesn't redirect to the thank-you page any more.

Here is the form code:

```
<form method="post" action="assets/sendmail.php">
<label for="name" class="nameLabel">Name</label>
<input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name...">
<label for="email" class="emailLabel">Email</label>
<input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email...">
<label for="subject">Subject</label>
<input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Your subject...">
<label for="message" class="messageLabel">Message</label>
<textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea>
<button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Here is the php code - note that I have substituted the email address for obvious reasons :)

```
<?php

// Email address verification
function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i", $email));
}

if($_POST) {

    // Enter the email where you want to receive the message
    $emailTo = 'me@myemail.com';

    $clientName = trim($_POST['name']);
    $clientEmail = trim($_POST['email']);
    $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
    $message = trim($_POST['message']);

    $array = array();
    $array['nameMessage'] = '';
    $array['emailMessage'] = '';
    $array['messageMessage'] = '';

    if($clientName == '') {
        $array['nameMessage'] = 'Please enter your name.';
    }
    if(!isEmail($clientEmail)) {
        $array['emailMessage'] = 'Please insert a valid email address.';
    }
    if($message == '') {
        $array['messageMessage'] = 'Please enter your message.';
    }
    if($clientName != '' && isEmail($clientEmail) && $message != '') {
        // Send email
    $headers = "From: " . $clientName . " <" . $clientEmail . ">" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $clientEmail;
    mail($emailTo, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }

    //echo json_encode($array);  
    { 
   header("location:../thankyou.html"); 
}

}

?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, have you posted the code wrong? I can see straight away that you have `{header("location:../thankyou.html"); }` without a condition before hand ...

Comment: no the condition is correct as the sendemail.php is in a subfolder inside the parent directory called assets.  The thank-you page is just in the parent directory, so in order to direct back out of the assets folder we use the ../ condition

Comment: The code (php) was working as it is above.  it has not been edited nor 'tampered with' I understand normally one would put something like an echo mail sent if it was valid and an else condition but the else condition is kind of covered in the code if conditions - i would think no need for an else

Comment: I have also moved the { header("location:../thankyou.html"); } to just above the //echo json_($array); but this has not done anything (with AND without the {})

Comment: In short, it was working properly, up until a day ago, now it is not, I cannot see why.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for email checking you can use built-in php as well.

```
filter_var($clientEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

I don't see where you output your errors so that may be why they are not showing,
I have added support for that

I have rewritten your code:

```
    <?php

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    // Enter the email where you want to receive the message
    $emailTo = 'me@myemail.com';

    $clientName = trim($_POST['name']);
    $clientEmail = trim($_POST['email']);
    $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
    $message = trim($_POST['message']);

    $errors = array();

    if (empty($clientName)) {
        $errors['nameMessage'] = 'Please enter your name.';
    }
    if (!filter_var($clientEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors['emailMessage'] = 'Please insert a valid email address.';
    }
    if (empty($message)) {
        $errors['messageMessage'] = 'Please enter your message.';
    }

    // Are there errors?
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        // Send email
        $headers = "From: " . $clientName . " <" . $clientEmail . ">" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $clientEmail;
        mail($emailTo, $subject, $message, $headers);
        header("location:../thankyou.html");
    } else {
        foreach ($errors as $err) {
            echo $err . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This explains where I was trying to come from Lol ... @Keith you need to ensure that there hasn't been anything outputted to the client, otherwise `header` wont work ... So the reason it's not accepting the `header` is most likely that the page is outputting errors

Comment: It would not post to email if there were errors.  The page is live not on a local server, if there were errors it should display in the contact window or a new page should it not?  I have purposely left errors and the email simply didn't send - but - it "was" all working fine including errors until the day I posted this question, then all of a sudden for no obvious reason it stopped working "properly".  Originally: if there were errors, it displayed errors in the relevant fields and did not send the email - if there were no errors, it sent the email and re-directed to the thankyou.html page.

Comment: Now if there are errors it does nothing, no errors displayed in the relevant fields and it does not send - so it is validating to a point but not displaying an error message.  If there are no errors, it does send - again obviously validating - but it is not directing/re-directing to the thankyou.html page.  So the user cannot know if the email was sent... Again it "was" working as it should have but now it is not.  And the new code Above from Mazzy does exactly the same thing.  It is obvious that it is going to the php as it does send, the php is the only place where the address is. puzzled :/

Answer (score 0):

Thank-you for the updated PHP code.  Unfortunately, it hasn't made any difference.  It still sends the email when all fields are filled in, it even sends if the "subject" is empty, but it still does not re-direct to the thank-you page.  It doesn't send if Name, Email Address, and Message are empty.  But it does not display errors.  I have tried to place both files in the parent directory and removing the assets/ from the action in the form and the ../ in the PHP. as below

```
<form method="post" action="sendmail.php">
<label for="name" class="nameLabel">Name</label>
<input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name...">
<label for="email" class="emailLabel">Email</label>
<input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email...">
<label for="subject">Subject</label>
<input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Your subject...">
<label for="message" class="messageLabel">Message</label>
<textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea>
<button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

And the PHP is as you supplied (changing the email address of course)

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    // Enter the email where you want to receive the message
    $emailTo = 'me@myemail.com';

    $clientName = trim($_POST['name']);
    $clientEmail = trim($_POST['email']);
    $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
    $message = trim($_POST['message']);

    $errors = array();

    if (empty($clientName)) {
        $errors['nameMessage'] = 'Please enter your name.';
    }
    if (!filter_var($clientEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors['emailMessage'] = 'Please insert a valid email address.';
    }
    if (empty($message)) {
        $errors['messageMessage'] = 'Please enter your message.';
    }

    // Are there errors?
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        // Send email
        $headers = "From: " . $clientName . " <" . $clientEmail . ">" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $clientEmail;
        mail($emailTo, $subject, $message, $headers);
        header("location:thankyou.html");
    }   else {
        foreach ($errors as $err) {
            echo $err . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

No Errors displayed if there are errors, no re-direct once sent.  It just remains on the "contact" page and still displaying the completed form.  Cannot understand why the re-direct was working but not now. Couldn't sign in when I posted this originally.

Comment: The above answer was done by me (Keith) I just could not sign into my account when I posted it

Comment: I have even put the entire URL in the header("location: http ://www.  sitename.com/thankyou. html")  (without the spaces of course)and still it does not re-direct, even if the page/address were wrong there should still be an error "page not found" but it just remains on the contact page as if nothing happened, but it does send the email, that's all it does.

Comment: Make sure ur PHP is not cached, shared hosting companies do that all the time.

Comment: I also have the feeling this is not all of your code, we cannot quess what code u are using so please share

Comment: Now I am really confused... The contact page in this query is in a folder inside my parent directory - it was working, now its not (properly)  I have created a new folder, taken the "form" section and placed it into a new contact.html page inside the new folder, I have created a new thankyou.html page and placed it into the new folder, I have copied the sendmail.php and placed it into the folder.  I uploaded it to the parent directory and tested it - it works it validates, displays errors, it sends if there are no errors, AND it re-directs to the thankyou-html page as it should.

Comment: But, the same code does not work in the original folder.  Each folder works independently they dont rely on files outside of their folders.  i have deleted all my history, cookies etc, i have copied the new files into the old folder and it still does not work in that folder, I have not added anything to the original folder that may cause it to not work... any ideas?